# NodeJS Sequelize ORM not recognise in Windows 10 CMD

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Please i need help. I use windows 10 OS and i am trying to use the Sequelize ORM dependency package/module in my NodeJS. I have installed the sequelize dependency and the sequelize-cli dependency package using npm and I confirmed a successful installation because i can find them in my package.json file.

The problem is everytime I try to run the sequelize command to create the model and other directories so that i can start using the ORM mapping in my NodeJS file the Windows 10 cmd returns that "sequelze is not recognized as an internal or external command". I know any command to be run in CMD would be added to the environment variable but sequelize is not a software that is installed but a module inside Node that is install through npm command.

How can i make Windows 10 recognize the sequelize command?

Please i will appreciate any help whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to install `sequelize-cli` globally to avoid such issues. This way it will be in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm` (which is added in PATH) as `sequelize.cmd`